# Adding Visual Studio Team Service agent

Tags: batch-file, cmd, azure-devops

For Microsoft's Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) I am trying to create an Agent.

I have downloaded the agent and put it on the server. Normally I run this manually by running the "ConfigureAgent.cmd" and enter the information it asks for and this works fine. I need to add agents to about 50 servers and am looking for a way I can bypass the manual entering of information.

The ConfigureAgent.cmd appears to mostly just call VSOAgent.exe

I checked what parameters it takes which seems to be pretty much all the fields I manually entered in.

I try this and receive the error "ErrorConnectingToTheServer
TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required."

The call to VSOAgent.exe that I use is

```
%~dp0Agent\VsoAgent.exe" /configure /RunningAsService /ServerUrl:SERVERURL /Name:"Agent-%ComputerName%" /PoolName:POOLNAME /Login:USERNAME,PASSWORD;AuthType=Basic /force /workfolder:"D:\VSOAgent\_work" /WindowsServiceLogonAccount:USERNAME /WindowsServiceLogonPassword:PASSWORD
```

Comment: What credential are you using for "/Login:USERNAME,PASSWORD;AuthType=Basic"?

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your command but didn't see any issue. However I can get "VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://xxx" error message if I try to login with my default VSTS account. Using "Alternate authentication credentials" works correctly. You can enable it from "My Profile\Security\Alternate authentication credentials" and then try again.
[image]

You can also create a "Personal access token" and login in with "PAT" authentication type.

> Common parameters
>
> /Login:UserName,Password[;AuthType=(AAD|Basic|PAT)]
>
> Used for configuration commands against a Team Services account. The parameter
>   is used to specify the pool administrator credentials. The credentials
>   are used to perform the pool administration changes and are not used
>   later by the agent. When using personal access tokens (PAT)
>   authentication type, specify anything for the user name and specify
>   the PAT as the password. If passing the parameter from PowerShell, be
>   sure to escape the semicolon or encapsulate the entire argument in
>   quotes. For example: '/Login:user,password;AuthType=PAT'. Otherwise
>   the semicolon will be interpreted by PowerShell to indicate the end of
>   one statement and the beginning of another.

Refer to this link for details: [Command-line parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/agents/windows#Command_lineparameters)