# Visual studio team foundation server web parts in SharePoint cannot connect to TFS 2015 Update 3

Tags: tfs, sharepoint-2013, tfs-2015

My SharePoint web sites not able to connect to TFS web parts like: Completed builds etc. The error is similar to [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42086321/an-error-occurred-while-sending-the-request-in-tfs2015-update2-vnext-build-confi)

TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server https://MyServer/tfs. Technical information (for administrator): The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

I believe the reason is same, that is TLS 1.0 disabling causing this too. But not able to figure out, how SharePoint is connected to TFS and which server i should put in the registry.

I have tried adding the .Net framework registry in the SharePoint server, that did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to TFS Administration Console and check the connection of SharePoint Web Application, to see whether the connection is still working.
2. Try to go to the TFS AT machine and access SharePoint site to see whether you have the same issue.
3. Configuring a SharePoint site to use HTTPS and certificates often requires additional steps, such as [configuring alternate access mappings](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc263208(v=office.15).aspx) and [configuring authentication infrastructure](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj219795(v=office.15).aspx). You may check detailed steps of setting up HTTPS with SSL for TFS at website below: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/setup-secure-sockets-layer#obtaining-a-certificate

Comment: My TFS url is configured with HTTPS, whereas the SharePoint is not.
I tried to access the SharePoint url from the TFS AT machine, i saw the same issue, now i have changed the reg entries in the SharePoint to use the TLS 1.2 forcefully, after reboot the problem is gone. thanks for the hint.